# Possible and/or wise to assign a method to a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm repeatedly trying to get similar data from time series dataframes. For example, the monthly (annualized) standard deviation of the series:

```
any_df.resample('M').std().mean()*12**(1/2)
```

It would save typing and would probably limit errors if these methods could be assigned to a variable, so they can be re-used - I guess this would look something like

```
my_stdev = .resample('M').std().mean()*12**(1/2)
result = any_df.my_stdev()
```

Is this possible and if so is it sensible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, that's not a method. Second, you need to go through a [basic Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and [learn to write a function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make your own function?

```
def my_stdev(df):
    return df.resample('M').std().mean()*12**(1/2)

result = my_stdev(any_df)
```

Comment: Thanks - that does indeed work. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.